# Parsing through a file

Tags: python, function, parsing, split

I have a .txt file with 10 lines and 3 columns, all tab delimitated. The columns contain numbers or  a ?. I want to parse through each line of the file and where a ? is found to call a certain function relating to the column the ? is found in. I have three functions so if a ? is found in column 1 then function_a is called, if its found in column 2 then function_b is called and if its found in column 3 then function_c is called.

I have looked at trying this:

```
for line in fileinput.readlines():
     print(line.split("?"))
```

but am not sure how to get a specific function called.

Comment: how do you define a column? You need to split by tab(`\t`), iterate over parts that split return, find which have `?` in them and then call your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be splitting on your delimiter to get each column's value for that row:

```
for line in fileinput.readlines():
    a, b, c = line.split('\t')      # Variable unpacking; assumes each line has three columns
    if a == '?':
        function_a()
    if b == '?':
        function_b()
    if c == '?':
        function_c()
```

Or if you're a fan of obnoxious and ugly one-liners:

```
[(function_a, function_b, function_c)[line.split('\t').index('?')]() for line in fileinput.readlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
def column_a(line):
    print 'first column in line', line

def column_b(line):
    print 'second column in line', line

def column_c(line):
    print 'third column in line', line

funcs = [column_a, column_b, column_c]

with open('input.txt') as fileinput:
    for line in fileinput.readlines():
        line = line.strip().split('\t')
        for i, item in enumerate(line):
            if item == '?':
                funcs[i](line)
```